# Disable 3 finger lookup in NSView using Swift

Tags: swift, macos, web, view

I am creating an online assessment application for Mac OSX in which there is a WebView which loads the assessment page.

I need this application to be secure and hence require that the three finger tap which brings up the Lookup option in a Mac be disabled. I am unable to figure out how to do it.

It's a Mac OSX application and not an iOS application so I don't want to use UIView solutions.

Comment: @David: re your edit, if you see [urgent begging or any other kind of hurrying](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/472495) in questions, it is best just removed.

Comment: @halfer - Noted. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The three-finger lookup is communicated using the `quickLook(with:)` function.  If you create a subclass of WebView and use that in your app, you can override that method to do nothing and thus prevent WebView from taking the default undesired action.